# How to activate item in QListwidget?

Tags: python, qt, qlistwidget

I would like to activate an item in a `QListWidget`?

For example I have a `QListWidget` called `lw_mask_items`.

```
lw_mask_items.addItem('Rectangle 1')
lw_mask_items.addItem('Rectangle 2')
lw_mask_items.addItem('Rectangle 3')
```

Can someone tell me how to select a specific item and activate it?

Comment: What do you mean with activate?

Comment: like clicked. But i don't want to click. I want to set it "clicked" in the code.

Comment: `item->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);` ?

Comment: So do you mean selected? You can use `QListWidgetItem::setSelected()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want just catch a selected item, you can use `QListWidget`'s signals `itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)` or `itemActivated(QListWidgetItem *item)`. If you want somehow activate custom item you can use `setItemSelected()` method or `setSelected()` of `QListWidgetItem`.

So, your code can be for example:

**.h side:**

```
<...>
    signals:
        void someSignal(const QString &data);

    public slots:
        void itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item);
        void someSlot(const QString &data);
}
```

**.cpp side:**

```
YourClass::YourClass()
{        
    lw_mask_items.addItem('Rectangle 1')
    lw_mask_items.addItem('Rectangle 2')
    lw_mask_items.addItem('Rectangle 3')
    connect(&lw_mask_items, &QListWidget::itemClicked, this, &YourClass::itemClicked);
    connect(this, &YourClass::someSignal, this, &YourClass::someSlot);
}

void YourClass::itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    // your code here
}

void YourClass::someSlot(const QString &data)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < wid.count(); i++)
        if(wid.item(i)->data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString().contains(data))
            wid.item(i)->setSelected(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:**

1. Select an item by setting the index in the underlying model
2. Activate an item by emitting the `activated` signal from the QListWidget

See (or just copy) the select_and_activate() function in the code below.

**Long answer:**

This is a rather clear question about a simple task, which I myself found amazingly complicated to accomplish in QT.

QT uses a View / Model approach for QListView and QListWidget. Although QListWidget ist a simplified version that doesn't require you to handle the model manually, you still need to deal with the internals of it when it comes to selecting an item.

To select the first entry, you have to set the index to that entry. To do that you need to access the underlying model.

Below you find an example (with hopefully useful comments). The main answer lies in the select_and_activate() function, which you can just copy for your own needs.

Please don't be confused by the variable name `listView`. I wrote the code for myself and I do use a list**View** instead of a List**Widget**.

Two caveats:

1. If you try to use this code on a ListView with an underlying FileSystem Model (which I do), you have to first set the index to the root item (which does not apply to a List**Widget**) and the select the row/index from there (index(row, 0, root_item)).
2. The order of items in the filesystem model is usually not the same as the order in the view. This is confusing. I selected the first item of the model, but it didn't appear on the first line of the view. Apparently the view gets sorted while the model gets not. After sorting the model items (which solved this problem), selecting item 0 (in the model) actually did select the first line (of the view). Without sorting it selected some "random" line of the view.

Here's the code of a complete working example. You can even select which item to highlight and activate from the command line.
`./select_and_activate.py 2` selects the third line
When you activate an item, the text of the item will be printed on standard output.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
# select_and_activate.py

import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QListWidget, QVBoxLayout


def select_and_activate(listView, row):

    # Get index of item with no. <row>
    index = listView.model().index(row, 0)

    # Make sure index is valid
    if(not index.isValid()):
        raise IndexError("Index ({}) not valid".format(row))

    # Set index (select item)
    listView.setCurrentIndex(index)

    # Activate entry
    listView.activated.emit(index)


def item_activated(index):

    # Print out text of activated item
    print("Item activated: {}".format(index.data()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Default selection (first line)
    selection = 0

    # Read optional selection from command line
    if(len(sys.argv) > 1):
        print("sys.argv: {}".format(sys.argv))
        selection = int(sys.argv[1])

    # Build main window with QListWidget
    window = QMainWindow()
    listView = QListWidget(window)
    window.setCentralWidget(listView)

    # Connect activation handler
    listView.activated.connect(item_activated)

    # Add three items
    listView.addItem("Hello, world!")
    listView.addItem("I'm the second line")
    listView.addItem("Why am I here?")

    # Select and activate first item
    select_and_activate(listView, selection)

    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```